# How to save the current url across page reload with Stash?

Tags: stash

I'm trying the following code to save the latest visited url across a page reload:

TEMPLATE A:

{exp:stash:set name="latest_url" scope="site" save="yes" refresh="60"}

{exp:current_url:full_url}

{/exp:stash:set}

TEMPLATE B:

{exp:stash:latest_url}

or

{exp:stash:get name='latest_url'}

--

There's no output, whatever I do!

But the current url is successfully grabbed in template A, which I can see, after turning output to "yes".

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you trying to make the saved url user-specific I would use scope="user", and add parse_tags="yes" and replace="yes" to the parameters. See if this works:

```
{exp:stash:set 
    name="latest_url" 
    scope="user" 
    save="yes" 
    replace="yes"
    parse_tags="yes"
    trim="yes"
}
    {exp:current_url:full_url}
{/exp:stash:set}

{exp:stash:get name="latest_url" scope="user"}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much, man. I was almost about to lose my mind about this! :)

Comment: One minor problem persists though! It seems that in Chrome only "favicon.ico" gets added as the last segment of the saved url. Any ideas on how to prevent this? Thanks!

Comment: OK, it seems it's also a problem in Firefox... :(

Comment: Alright, I fixed it using ce_string to trim the last segment! Thanks! :)